# How to make vertical space between div tags?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have three div tags and i want to make space between the div tags vertically and also want my first div tag as a fixed one.

When i set my first div position as *not a fixed* one, i can *able to make vertical space*.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>div</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<div style="width:100%; background-color:Lime;">
<div style="width:100%; height:10%; background-color:Blue;">
a
</div>
<div style="width:70%; height:100%; background-color:Gray; margin: auto; margin-top: 2em; margin-bottom: 2em;">
b
</div>
<div style="width:100%; height:5%; background-color:Aqua;">
c
</div>        
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i change my *"div a"* position as *fixed* , both *"div a" and "div b"* came down from the margin-top: 2em.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>div</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<div style="width:100%; background-color:Lime;">
<div style="width:100%; height:10%; background-color:Blue; position: fixed;">
a
</div>
<div style="width:70%; height:100%; background-color:Gray; margin: auto; margin-top: 2em; margin-bottom: 2em;">
b
</div>
<div style="width:100%; height:5%; background-color:Aqua;">
c
</div>        
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me to make my *"div a"* as *fixed* and to make *space* between *"div a and b"*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to keep `div.a` (the fixed one) to the top of the page, add `top: 0;` and if you want it to stay on top of the rest of the content, include `z-index: 2;`.

In order to add spacing between `div.a` and `div.b` you are going to have to put a container `div` around `div.b` and appropriate padding to it. If you just put padding on the main container div it will offset `div.a`.

If possible, set a definitive height to `div.a`, instead of a percentage, as this will make the vertical alignment of `div.b` and it's container much easier. That way you can set the `margin-top` for `div.b` to be the `height` of `div.a`.

Below is the CSS and HTML refactored for better readability:

```css
/* CSS */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
}
div.container {
  height: 100%;
}
div.container,
div.b-container {
  background-color: lime;
}
div.a {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
div.b-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 2em;
  margin-top: 70px;
}
div.b-container div.b {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: auto;
  
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
div.c {
  height: 5%;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="b-container">
    <div class="b">b
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    c
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your other two divs as fixed too, keeping the margin-top: 2em parameter

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can make spaces but i can't able to view full page. I can't able to scroll down...

Comment: replace margin-top by padding-top, see if that helps

Comment: clean and effective one

Answer (score 1):

when you set it to fixed it takes it out of the normal document flow. thats why the other elemts are getting lost under it.  add a top: 0; to div a and change the margin-top for div b worked for me. its atleast a starting point. im not sure what the end result your looking for. check out the link

http://jsfiddle.net/8ar3kvep/

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<div style="width:100%; background-color:Lime;">
<div style="width:100%; height:10%; background-color:Blue; position: fixed; top:0;">
a
</div>
<div style="width:70%; height:100%; background-color:Gray; margin: auto; margin-top: 
4em; 
margin-bottom: 2em;">
b
</div>
<div style="width:100%; height:5%; background-color:Aqua;">
c
</div>        
</div>
</body>
```